# Random banking type authentication using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a task of trying to enter authentication details for a memorable word field like for online banking where you have a 8 digit number and you will be prompted for a random selection of these.

The number is displayed next to the input box `'Enter 5th character'`.

Input box field:

```
<input style="border:none;" size="1" maxlength="1" type="password" name="e0" id="eid1" class="mem" value="" tabindex="1">

<input style="border:none;" size="1" maxlength="1" type="password" name="e1" id="eid2" class="mem" value="" tabindex="1">
```

All the information is held within a `tr` for each box as below:

```
<tr>
    <td class="white"><input type="hidden" name="0" value="5">Enter  8th character </td>
    <td class="Mem"><input style="border:none;" size="1" maxlength="1" type="password" name="e0" id="eid1" class="memCd" value="" tabindex="1"></td>
</tr>
```

Has anyone come across this with selenium before?

EDITED

The form looks like this

```
<form method="POST" action="nextStage.php" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" id="returnid" value="" />
    <table align="center" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4">
        <tbody><tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="0" value="0" />Enter  1st character </td>
        <td colspan="2"><input size="1" maxlength="1" type="password" name="e0" id="eid1" class="enterDetails" value="" tabindex="1" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="1" value="2" />Enter  3rd character </td>
        <td colspan="2"><input size="1" maxlength="1" type="password" name="e1" id="eid2" class="enterDetails" value="" tabindex="2" /></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="2" value="4" />Enter  5th character </td>
        <td colspan="2"><input size="1" maxlength="1" type="password" name="e2" id="eid3" class="enterDetails" value="" tabindex="3" /></td>
```

EDIT to show new code

```
pattern = re.compile(r"Enter (\d+)\w+ character of memorable word")
number_string = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#homePane > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)").text
number = int(pattern.search(number_string).group(1))

target_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#homePane > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type=password]")
target_input.send_keys(secret_string[number])

number_string = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#homePane > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1)").text
number = int(pattern.search(number_string).group(1))

target_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#homePane > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type=password]")
target_input.send_keys(secret_string[number])


number_string = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#homePane > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(1)").text
number = int(pattern.search(number_string).group(1))
target_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#homePane > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type=password]")
target_input.send_keys(secret_string[number])
```

Comment: try using the array option for the name i.e. e[0] ect and then check the requested letter against the array index of the string. A string is essentially an array of chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the `input` with `Enter Nth character` text using, for example, a CSS selector, extract the `N` number from the text, get the character from the secret string by index and send it to the password `input`:

```
import re

secret_string = "secret string"

pattern = re.compile(r"Enter (\d+)\w+ character")

number_string = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr > td.white > input").text
number = int(pattern.search(number_string).group(1))

target_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr > td.mem > input[type=password]")

target_input.send_keys(secret_string[number])
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm getting File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    number_string = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr > td.white > input").text
 Message: u'no such element\n

Comment: This might help that Xpath and css are    //*[@id="formMemWord"]/table/tbody/tr[1]
     
     #formMemWord > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)

Comment: @Grimlockz do you have any `iframe` or `frame` elements on the page?

Comment: I can't see any frame elements on the page  - When I try to do css or xpath for any of the 3 random fields it can't see to find any of them  #formMemWord > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td.white > input[type="hidden"]
     
     //*[@id="formMemWord"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/text()   - Is there any other information I can give you?

Comment: @Grimlockz you may try to explicitly wait for an input to become present. Also, is this a public site and you can share a link? Thanks

Comment: Sadly the link is not public as its a private test server, I might be being slow but how would waiting for an input to become present help as its a static form? Thanks for your by the way

Comment: @Grimlockz it could be that the input elements or the form itself are not yet present at the time the search is performed. Adding an Explicit wait can help with that.

Comment: Sadly still getting the same with a 10 second delay to the page

Comment: @alecxa - Actually looking at the code it has header("X-Frame-Options: DENY"); which I believed is a security measure - would this cause a issue?

Comment: @Grimlockz don't think so. What is your current code and error you are getting? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to copy xpath and css path from chrome console then add that it but it comes up with element unknown -  number_string = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#formMemWord > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.white").text

Comment: I think I got a bit further as there are three different fields to enter it looks like the css is #homePane > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) for the first one then (2) and (3) for the other two -  error now is - number = int(pattern.search(number_string).group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @Grimlockz ok, I've updated the regular expression in the answer, please recheck. And thanks for the updates.

Comment: @alexca its looks like the regular expression worked for that section now getting element not found for "tr > td.mem > input[type=password]"  - The css picks it up as #homePane > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)

Comment: @alexca I've updated the question with the your code and now it enters all the characters but when trying to log it's the wrong password so not sure what has happened  - Also this sometimes appears when trying to do one of the boxes  target_input.send_keys(secret_string[number])
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Just to update - Secret string is set to "987654" - Changing the password field shows that its added number 5 when the field asked for the 4th character, number 7 when the field asked for 2nd character, and a repeat test shows 3rd character as 6, 1st character as 8 and 2nd character as 7

Comment: Got it to work by adding in a blank character at the start of the secret string